# In Powershell read multiple files and count the no. of lines in each file. Then write all this information in a single CSV file

Tags: powershell

I need to read multiple files and count the no. of lines in each file. Then write all this information in a single CSV file with the file path information.

I could write a code (with help from forums) that will help to read all files and print the information as required.

**Script:**

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Logs\test *.log | Select-Object -Property FullName,@{Name="LineCount";$Expression={@(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Length}}
```

**Output of script:**

```text
FullName                    LineCount
--------                    ---------
C:\Logs\test\ANCD065.log          296
C:\Logs\test\ANCE066.log          287
```

**Problems:**

1. The problem is not able to write the above information in a CSV file.

```sh
Write "what parameter need pass not clear to me" | Out-File C:\Log\OP.CSV
```

2. The script reads all lines, is there a way to start reading line after certain lines? An example in the given file need is count lines from line 9 (start) to the end(could be 300).

```text
1.     3.03           MET DATA                                RINEX VERSION / TYPE
2. cnvtToRINEX 3.14.0  convertToRINEX OPR  20220511 072939 UTC PGM / RUN BY / DATE 
3. ----------------------------------------------------------- COMMENT            
4. XYXTY3                                                       MARKER NAME         
5. UBWTZ3                                                       MARKER NUMBER       
6.     3    PR    TD    HR                                    # / TYPES OF OBSERV 
7.  0083019.4060  0025010.0967  0253356.6176        0.0000 PR SENSOR POS XYZ/H    
8.                                                            END OF HEADER      
9. 19 03 02 00 00 00  946.0    8.5   93.0
10. 19 03 02 00 05 00  946.0    8.4   93.4
11. 19 03 02 00 10 00  946.0    8.4   93.4
12. 19 03 02 00 15 00  946.0    8.4   94.2
13. 19 03 02 00 20 00  946.0    8.5   93.1
14. 19 03 02 00 25 00  946.1    8.7   90.2
15. 19 03 02 00 30 00  946.2    8.4   92.0
16. 19 03 02 00 35 00  946.3    8.3   93.2
```

Comment: Please [format your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/601145) so it's easier for others to read. *"The problem is not able to write the above information in a CSV file."* - Okay, where is your code that is attempting to write this data to the CSV file? We can't help debug what we can't see. *"The script reads all lines, is there a way to start reading line after certain lines?"* - Not really, because this isn't how files work. You can start reading after a certain number of characters, but the only way to count the number of line breaks is to read the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is not able to write the above information in a CSV file.

This should be as simple as appending an `Export-Csv` command to the pipeline:

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Logs\test *.log | 
    Select-Object -Property @(
        'FullName'
         @{ Name = "LineCount"; Expression = { 
             @(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Length
         }} 
    ) |
    Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note that my `Select-Object` changes are just for code readability.

> The script reads all lines, is there a way to start reading line after
> certain lines? An example in the given file need is count lines from
> line 9 (start) to the end(could be 300).

You may use `Select-Object -Skip n` to skip given number of lines from the beginning. Another improvement is to use `Measure-Object` to count number of items. In your current code, you have to read the whole log file into an array in memory, before being able to count lines. With `Measure-Object`, the file will be streamed, requiring much less memory for processing.

```sh
(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 8 | Measure-Object).Count
```

**Complete solution:**

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Logs\test *.log | 
    Select-Object -Property @(
        'FullName'
         @{ Name = "LineCount"; Expression = { 
             (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 8 | Measure-Object).Count
         }} 
    ) |
    Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The complete solution does not write the count of the number of lines.

Comment: @HawfinchTaylor I've just fixed a mistake - remove `Measure-Object` parameter `-Count`.

Comment: Just removed the -Count and it works and writes the count of the number of lines.

`Get-ChildItem -Path C:\log *.log | 
    Select-Object -Property @(
        'FullName'
         @{ Name = "LineCount"; Expression = { 
             (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 8 | Measure-Object).Count
         }} 
    ) |
    Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: zett42 - Is there a way to skip the line based on the character/string which is "END OF HEADER"? In the original problem, the header ends at line 8 but in actuality, it varies from 8-15 lines. So the `-skip` doesn't fit well. I created a new [query] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75083300/reading-lines-and-get-total-line-after-a-known-text-in-a-file/75083859?noredirect=1#comment132503252_75083859)  but the solution failed to give output (alteast for me with my limited knowledge)