# Reading lines and get total line after a known text in a file

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that reads lines and then writes line count in a .csv file. The script skips the first 8 lines (header of the file) and counts the remaining lines to get the count of lines.

**Script**

```sh
$targDir = "C:\Logs\15Sec\Ref.Data\Month\";
$subDir = $(Get-ChildItem "$targDir" –Directory );
foreach($sub in $subDir) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $sub –Recurse *.log | 
    Select-Object -Property @(
        'FullName'
         @{ Name = "LineCount"; Expression = { 
             (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 8 | Measure-Object).Count
         }} 
    ) |
    Export-Csv "C:\test\$($sub.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

**Problem**

Sometimes the file header doesn't limit to the first 8 lines. It gets extended to 11 or 15 lines depending on the information/comments in the header.

This gives a wrong count of the total lines because the need is to count lines only after the end of the header.

Each file header ends with the text "END OF HEADER".

How to modify the script to start counting lines only after the text "END OF HEADER".

**File Header**

the actual file doesn't have 1., 2., 3. numbering, I have added it here for line count reference only

```text
1.     3.03           MET DATA                                RINEX VERSION / TYPE
2. cnvtToRINEX 3.14.0  convertToRINEX OPR  20220511 072939 UTC PGM / RUN BY / DATE 
3. ----------------------------------------------------------- COMMENT            
4. XYXTY3                                                       MARKER NAME         
5. UBWTZ3                                                       MARKER NUMBER       
6.     3    PR    TD    HR                                    # / TYPES OF OBSERV 
7.  0083019.4060  0025010.0967  0253356.6176        0.0000 PR SENSOR POS XYZ/H    
8.                                                            END OF HEADER      
9. 19 03 02 00 00 00  946.0    8.5   93.0
10. 19 03 02 00 05 00  946.0    8.4   93.4
11. 19 03 02 00 10 00  946.0    8.4   93.4
12. 19 03 02 00 15 00  946.0    8.4   94.2
```

Comment: Does the actual file contain the line numbers (`1.`, `2.`, `3.` etc.), or did you add those?

Comment: No, the actual file doesn't contain (1., 2., 3).  I added just for reference here

Comment: As an aside: In PowerShell you never need to use `$(...)` on the RHS of an assignment; in your case, `$subDir = Get-ChildItem "$targDir" –Directory` will do (also without `;`, which is only ever needed for placing multiple statements on the _same line_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @MathiasR.Jessen, the correct line of code is -

````
@{ Name = "LineCount"; Expression = { 
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Where({$_ -match "END OF HEADER"}, 'SkipUntil').Count - 1
}}```
````

Comment: An explanation to the answer is already @MathiasR.Jessen. In addition to the above explanation - `-match` is used to validate if the characters exist or not. -Match returns True output, otherwise False. The correct syntax is - `-match "POP MUSIC"`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Select -Skip`, use the [intrinsic `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.3#where) in `SkipUntil` mode - this will ignore all lines prior to the line containing `END OF HEADER` and the count of post-header lines is thus the count minus 1:

```
@{ Name = "LineCount"; Expression = { 
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Where({$_ -match '\bEND OF HEADER\b'}, 'SkipUntil').Count - 1
}}
```

Comment: I am getting LineCount as -1

Comment: @HawfinchTaylor that would indicate `END OF HEADER` isn't found in any lines in the file

Comment: But each and every file have END OF HEADER text

Comment: I could figure out the problem with the solution. If I pass `-match "END OF HEADER`, the output produces the exact count of lines ignoring all lines above the text.

Comment: The correct code of line is `@{ Name = "LineCount"; Expression = { 
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Where({$_ -match "END OF HEADER"}, 'SkipUntil').Count - 1
}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
$targDir = "C:\Logs\15Sec\Ref.Data\Month\";
$subDir = $(Get-ChildItem "$targDir" –Directory );
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($sub in $subDir) {
Write-Host "sub = " $sub
    $filenames = Get-ChildItem -Path ($sub.Name + "*.log") -Recurse -Force
    foreach($filename in $filenames)
    {
Write-Host "filename = " $filename
       $text = Get-Content -Path $filename
       $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
       $dashLine = $text | select-string -Pattern "---------------" |select LineNumber
       $totalLines = $text | Measure-Object –Line
       $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Filename -NotePropertyValue $filename
       $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName NumberLines -NotePropertyValue ($totalLines.Lines - $dashLine.LineNumber)
       $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
    }
}
$table | Export-Csv "C:\test\$($sub.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I am not sure how to fit this into my current script. Also, I am reading multiple files which are stored in subdirectories.

Comment: I updated code.  You can use Add-Member to add additional columns to the csv.  You probably want to add the filename.

Comment: In the above code "test.txt" is referring to a single file. may I ask you how the code will read all files with different names?

Comment: I updated code base on your code.  Added another ChildItem to get files and a for loop.  Didn't test.  The code could be simplified and find all log files in $targDir and use only one for loop.

Comment: When I run the code, get the following error - `+ $table | "C:\test\$($sub.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-NoTypeInformation' in expression or statement.
At line:17 char:10
+ $table | "C:\test\$($sub.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken`

Comment: I lost Export-CSV

Comment: Now no error but the output has a blank csv file (no data) and second csv file name is just .csv (folder name is not appended). This is case when there are only 2 folders present

Comment: You code is getting all directories which includes the root folder where the name is just a period and two periods (\. and \..).   The code works on my PC with different folders.  You need to debug the $filenames line to see what is wrong with Get-ChildItems.  May just be missing a backslash after folder name.